# AWS ECS Fargate: How to create a service with auto scaling with the service API

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

I do not understand how I can create auto scaling for a ecs fargate service with the API. I create my service with code like this with the ecs [create service api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateService.html):

```
{    
    "serviceName": "my-service",
    "cluster": "my-cluster",
    "taskDefinition": "my-task",
    "desiredCount": 1,
    "launchType": "FARGATE",
    "loadBalancers":[
        {
            "targetGroupArn": my_target_group_arn,
            "containerName": "my-container-nginx",
            "containerPort": 8090
        }        
    ],
    "networkConfiguration": {
        'awsvpcConfiguration': {
            'subnets': settings.AWS_SUBNET_IDS,
            'securityGroups': [securitygroup_id]
        }
    },   

}
```

How to add the auto scaling, which I can configure in the AWS console in the browser easily? Do I have to create a capacityProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/create-step-scaling-policy-cli.html) walks you through how to configure a service autoscaling policy for ECS via the CLI. Note that often the console provides a "macro" experience to make all the steps easier whereas if you have to do the same with the CLI/API it's often multiple steps (as outlined in the doc).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like what I was looking for. I did not understand how the different aws resources are related to each other.